# Export iterator from a module to allow iterating over asterisk imports

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, iterable

I have an index file with multiple re-exports

```
// things/index.js
export { a } from 'a'
export { b } from 'b'
export { c } from 'c'
```

Now I want to use all the *things* in another file as arguments to my function.
*This actually works:*

```
import * as things from './things'

things[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  for (let v in this) { yield v }
}

function print(things) {
  [...things].forEach(thing => {
    console.debug('thing', thing)
  });
}

print(things)

// prints:
// thing a
// thing b
// thing c
```

I would like to avoid having to set an iterator this way and instead export it together with the *things*. Is there a way?

Comment: "*This actually works*" - are you using a transpiler? In pure ES6, a namespace object like `things` is immutable, you cannot add a symbol to it.

Comment: @Bergi Good point, yes, the code is transpiled to ES5 with TypeScript.

Comment: Btw, instead of making the exports object iterable, I think you should just enumerate it with `for … in` or `Object.values`. Or if you care about ordering them, then export an array with the values.

Comment: The point was using `doSomething([...things])` without having to reimplement the function `doSomething`, but yes, I have ultimately resorted to `Object.values`, though I think this question is still valid as it is even though the answer is `don't` __*;'D*__

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using separate named exports, consider having a *single* export (named or otherwise), which is an object with `a`, `b`, `c` properties, *and* has a `Symbol.iterator` property:

```
// things/index.js
import { a } from 'a'
import { b } from 'b'
import { c } from 'c'
export const things = {
  a,
  b,
  c,
  [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
    yield a;
    yield b;
    yield c;
  }
};
```

Or iterate over the values (the `Symbol.iterator` property won't be included while iterating, since it's not enumerable):

```
// things/index.js
import { a } from 'a'
import { b } from 'b'
import { c } from 'c'
export const things = {
  a,
  b,
  c,
  [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
    yield* Object.values(this);
  }
};
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of the single-line export from statements, also I would have to refactor large sets of files, instead of simply adding an additional export. But I hear that an export with computed name isn't possible, so is this my only option?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you can't export a `[Symbol.iterator]` property of the namespace, at least not if you're using `export` syntax. (though it'd be doable If you were using `require` syntax, whose import/export mechanics use plain Javascript expressions, rather than the special syntax of `import` and `export`)

Comment: There is [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports), which could make things more DRY, but it's less supported and requires asynchronous usage, so I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: Instead of that generator function with the array iteration, just use `[Symbol.iterator]() { return Object.values(this).values(); }`. Or `yield* Object.values(this)`.

Comment: @Bergi Every day you learn something new, could you please point me somewhere where I can read that it's ok to `return iterable`? I have also just learned that _`yield* expression` is used to delegate to another generator or iterable object._

Comment: @Qwerty the `return` is with [an iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values), not an iterable.